# Use of countByKeyApprox() for Partial manual broadcast hash join

Tags: apache-spark

I read about Partial manual broadcast hash join which can be used while joining Pair RDD in Spark. This is suggested to be useful if one key is so large that it can’t fit on a single partition. In this case you can use countByKeyApprox on the large RDD to get an approximate idea of which keys would most benefit from a broadcast.
You then filter the smaller RDD for only these keys, collecting the result locally in a HashMap. Using sc.broadcast you can broadcast the HashMap so that each worker only has one copy and manually perform the join against the HashMap. Using the same HashMap you can then filter your large RDD down to not include the large number of duplicate keys and perform your standard join, unioning it with the result of your manual join. This approach is quite convoluted but may allow you to handle highly skewed data you couldn’t otherwise process.

The question is about the usage of countByKeyApprox(long timeout). What is the unit of this timeout? IF I write countByKeyApprox(10), does that mean it will wait for 10 seconds or 10 ms or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in milliseconds
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html#countByKeyApprox-long-double-

> **Parameters:**
>
> - timeout - maximum time to wait for the job, in milliseconds
> - confidence - the desired statistical confidence in the result